# Zend Sessions getting error as Undefined Variable

Tags: zend-framework

If I Declare a session Variable, `$_SESSION['user']= $user;`, I will get error as

```
Undefined Variable _session in line 132.
```

I really appreciate any help regarding this problem.

Comment: Are you using a really ancient version of PHP? <4.1?

Comment: you will have to provide more details. are you using this as a part of a zend framework app?

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini declare

session.auto_start = 0

OR

use session_start(); before using any session variable. More preciously:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']= $user;
```